# conda and python shell scripts

Tags: python, shell, unix

Suppose I have a python shell script of the usual shebang kind (let's suppose it's in a file called `foo.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Hello World")
```

with the twist that I need to run it in a given python environment Now, of course, I can write a script of the following kind:

```
#!/bin/sh
conda activate myenv
exec foo.py
```

But this is mildly unsatisfying aesthetically. Is there a way to package the environment into the script to avoid the extra level of scripting?

Comment: find the python executable of your environment and put it into the first line

Comment: Will this be used by just you? Or are you packaging for other people to run? In other words, can you guarantee that you will always have the right environment on the system?

Comment: @jwillis0720 in the use that provoked the question, I was actually just using the `base` environment, so that should not be a serious issue, but in general, that is an excellent question, and I assume that short of containerizing there is nothing one can do...

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1: explicit interpreter path**

You can explicitly find the path to the python interpreter in your environment and use that in the shebang:

```
source activate myenv
which python
```

Will output something like `/Users/me/anaconda/envs/myenv/bin/python`. You can then write the python script's shebang using that full path:

```
#!/Users/me/anaconda/envs/myenv/bin/python
...
```

However, it's still kinda ugly.

**Option 2: symlinks**

`#!/usr/bin/env python` just looks through `$PATH` for something called "`python`" and uses that to run the script. We can use this behavior to get nicer shebangs for our conda environments.

Here's a script to add symlinks in `~/bin` for each conda environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
conda_prefix="$HOME/anaconda" # Modify this line if your anaconda folder is somewhere else
mkdir -p "$HOME/bin" # Make ~/bin if it doesn't exist
for env_dir in "$conda_prefix/envs/"*; do
    env_name=$(basename "$env_dir")
    ln -s "$env_dir/bin/python" "$HOME/bin/$env_name"
    echo "Made symlink for environment $env_name"
done
```

Once you've run that once (and you've [added `$HOME/bin` to your `$PATH`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path) in `.profile`), you can reference conda envs directly in the shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env myenv
...
```

This will find `myenv` in the `$PATH` as `$HOME/bin/myenv`, which is a symlink to `$HOME/anaconda/envs/myenv/bin/python` thanks to our script above.